# Authentication with JWT in React and Node-Express using Github OAuth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have been trying to implement Google and Github OAuth authentication in one of my projects which uses React on the client side and NodeJS-Express on the backend. After going through dozens of articles and several Youtube videos later, here's what I have discovered about OAuth.

There are two main flows in OAuth. **Authorization Code Grant Flow** and **Implicit Flow**. To be on the same page, I would elaborate what I understood about both of these flows in short:

*Authorization Code Grant Flow* : User(resource owner) clicks on Login with Google/Github and is then redirected to the consent screen. Once they give consent, user(resource owner) is redirected back to the callback_url with a authorization_code in the URL query parameter. The  authorization code is then send to the backend server. The server then makes a request to the authorization server of the OAuth provider along with the client_id,client_secret and the authorization code and then receives a access_token as well as a refresh_token required to access the resource server.

*Implicit Flow* : It is sort of a hacky way that was proposed back in the day for Single Page Applications as CORS wasn't properly implemented in all the browsers. Here  the Single Page Application is given the access_token once the resource owner has given consent to the OAuth provider and it is now the duty of the SPA to store the access_token in a protected manner. However, since browsers aren't really trustworthy, and CORS is a real thing now, the  Implicit flow is not really recommended anymore.If someone wants to implement the Implicit FLow, PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) is sort of the standard now.

**What I tried to implement**

I decided to go ahead with Authorization Code Grant Flow as it seemed the most secure to me and also I have a backend server to handle the authorization code exchange.

Here is what **most people** suggest in order to implement Authorization Code Grant Flow with React.

Render a link like this.

```
<a href='http://localhost:8000/auth'>Login With Github</a>
```

Now handle this endpoint in the backend

```
app.get('/auth',(req,res)=>{
   res.redirect(githubOAuthConsentScreenURL)
})
```

Now handle the redirect_uri in the backend and make a post request to the authorization server to get a access_token

```
app.get('/auth/callback',(req,res)=>{
   //Extract the authorization code from query params and make a POST request to get back the access_token
})
```

Passport JS also implements this approach which is handling the callback url on the server.

Here is what **I** thought of doing:

Handle the callback URL on client side i.e. with React. Extract the authorization code from the parameters and then make a XHR call to the server with it. The server will now exchange the authorization code for an access_token and make a request to get the user's profile data. If everything succeeds, the Express backend will return a short lived access_token and a long lived refresh_token which will then be used by the React application to access the REST API.

**My question here is :** Which method is correct and the standard way to do authentication, handling the callback_url on the server or on the client side?. The method I propose over here seems more logical to me. Does my method have any security flaws compared to the other one? Am I missing something?

**Other things that I have confusions about :**

How is OAuth vulnerable to CSRF? From what I read, the state parameter can be used to protect the OAuth flow against CSRF. However, if I am redirecting the user from my backend server and then handling the callback_url in the server as well, how do I remember the state variable apart from storing it in some sort of session/db. Is it not more logical to redirect the user from the browser? Then the state parameter can be stored in the localStorage and can be matched later during the callback.

Also, I am implementing a short lived access_token and a long lived refresh_token for authentication and storing both the tokens as httpOnly cookie. If my access_token is stored as a httpOnly cookie, then how do I know if I am logged in or not and persist the state in React. One solution (proposed by Ben Awad in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsaOTcBe-dM&t=182s)) was to query for the user during initial load and if the query succeeds, store the state (maybe in Redux) and then conditionally render the routes.

Is this the correct way of doing this? If not what is the standard manner that is followed by React applications which are actually in production? Again, am I missing something here?

**Please Note :** I am pretty new to authentication, would appreciate all the help and detailed explanations.